# How to avoid the data in a QlistView getting blanked out on a double click?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, model-view-controller

I am using QListView to show some data and allow user to change the records in-place.

I have the following code that enables a user to double click an item and rename it:

```
listView_->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::DoubleClicked |
                             QAbstractItemView::SelectedClicked);
```

However, when the user clicks on it, the data gets blanked out. I want the current data to remain there and the user can edit it.

How can I make this happen ?

Here are my `setData()`, `data()` and `flags()` implementations -

```
bool
myModel::setData(const QModelIndex & index,
  const QVariant & value, int role) {
  if (index.isValid() && role == Qt::EditRole)  {
    stringModel_.replace(index.row(), value.toString());
    emit dataChanged(index, index);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

QVariant
myModel::data(const QModelIndex &index,
    int role) const {
  if (index.isValid() && index.row() <= stringModel_.size()
      && role == Qt::DisplayRole) {
    return stringModel_[index.row()];
  }
  else {
    return QVariant();
  }
}

Qt::ItemFlags
myModel::flags(const QModelIndex & index) const {
  if (!index.isValid()) {
    return Qt::ItemIsEnabled;
  }
  return QAbstractItemModel::flags(index) | Qt::ItemIsEditable;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `Qt::EditRole` in your `data()` implementation.

```
QVariant
myModel::data(const QModelIndex &index,
    int role) const {
  if (index.isValid() && index.row() <= stringModel_.size()
      && (role == Qt::DisplayRole || role == Qt::EditRole) ) {
    return stringModel_[index.row()];
  }
  else {
    return QVariant();
  }
}
```